# Using Drools for logic gates

Tags: drools

We have been given two configurations (of Logic gates). Suppose

LHS = A.(B + C) and

RHS = B.A + C.A

What we have to find out are the rules applied to LHS so that we get RHS finally. We have to print the intermediate rules.
For example.. output in this case will be

A.(B + C) = A.B + A.C

A.B = B.A

A.C = C.A

The operations which would be applied on LHS to get RHS would be the answer.
We are working on Drools. We have to make a drl file for it. But I am totally confused about the rules. We have to make the rules containing the operations.

I have not been able to figure out how the thing will work through drools.

Please provide some hints.

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding your post, could you rephrase it? Is there a question?

Comment: Sorry if the way of asking was confusing. Well I changed the question.. Hope I make myself clear this time.